# 2004 Taurus - Help Identifying the leaking component

Tags: ford, exhaust, leak, taurus

I was changing the oil on my 2004 Ford Taurus and I noticed this fairly aggressive leak. Can someone please help me identify this component and identify this leak? Any suggestions on correction?

[image: Leak]

Answer (score 9):

The left descending pipe is (or comes from) the exhaust manifold, and ends in a two-bolt flange. The flange bolts to a matching flange on the front end of the exhaust pipe, which runs aft from the flanged connection towards the rear of the car, undoubtedly through a muffler (or two).

Gaskets in such high-heat environments are often made of metal; this one appears to be so. Because one can see a strip of gasket outside the flange faces, we can judge that the gasket is failing.

The repair is to remove the two bolts (and, perhaps, whatever mounts are aft of the flanged connection, so that the exhaust pipe can be moved slightly), open the flanged joint, remove whatever portion of the original gasket remains and make sure the flange surfaces are clean and dry, replace the old gasket with a new one, and reassemble the joint. You may want to apply some anti-sieze paste on the bolt threads before reassembly.

Comment: Beat me to the punch. Great answer and +1
!

Comment: Thank you so much. What risk does this type of leak pose?

Comment: The leak itself, however, is likely to be mere condensation. (Funny how I say 'mere', yet it's the cause why exhaust systems rust from the inside out...)

It could also be rainwater or HVAC water discharge if the condenser is that far back.

Comment: ^^ Rusting, which is a big reason why holes appear in your exhaust. Try and get it sorted out. Also, if you remove the bolts, I recommend wire wheelin' the threads on them. Keep them as rust-free as possible.

Comment: @yollooool - Good advice. I'd also recommend PB Blaster on it, as it penetrates rust *really* well. Use it every time I take exhaust parts apart.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I personally use 50% Acetone and 50% ATF for a penetrating and anti-rust measure, though either works.
Actually, to put towards that note, if you do do (Childish time: DooDoo) the exhaust system gasket replacement, I'd spray some penetrating fluid on it every day for three days before you come to play with it. It will come off and almost certainly avoid stripping nuts/bolts.

I'd actually go so far as to use a copper grease on the bolts before you put them back in, although this being on an exhaust system, it may not be the smartest idea seeing as it gets VERY hot.

Comment: Which blaster product would you use @Paulster2? There's several choices, do you mean the penetrating catalyst?

Comment: Should I be concerned that it is green fluid? It seems to be antifreeze.